# Razor Tag Helpers In Pre-ASP.NET Core MVC Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In ASP.NET Core there is a new feature called "tag helpers", where I can replace my razor syntax

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

with something a bit more natural

```
<input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
```

- Is this feature available in Pre-ASP.NET Core?
- If not, will it come to Pre-ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag helpers live in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace which replaces the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace used in earlier versions of ASP.NET.

So it is not available in Pre-ASP.NET Core versions.  And I seriously doubt it ever will be.  Microsoft would have to go back and make serious changes to `System.Web.Mvc`.  They've stated many times that they are moving away from `System.Web`.